# Collection View automatically handles large amounts of records?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8, uicollectionview

I have a variable that holds a collection of records from Core Data. Sometimes it can be thousands of records. If I feed this variable into a collection view, does it automatically handle large amount?

What I am hoping is that the collection is lazy loaded into the variable from Core Data and the collection view loads 10-20 at a time just to handle the viewport. Is this too good to be true or what's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [AshFurrow's](https://github.com/ashfurrow/UICollectionView-NSFetchedResultsController) implementation of a fetched results controller with a collection view.
Then when you lazy load your fetched results controller, just set your batch size.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Your added implementation
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    // More code...
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Below is AshFurrow's NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate implementation for which I leave as is. Then use your fetchedResultsController within your collection view delegate/dataSource methods quite similarly to how you would in a table view.

```
// GitHub : AshFurrow FetchedResultsController + CollectionView    
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
// Begin updates
    _objectChanges = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    _sectionChanges = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert || type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {
        NSMutableIndexSet *changeSet = _sectionChanges[@(type)];
        if (changeSet != nil) {
            [changeSet addIndex:sectionIndex];
        } else {
            _sectionChanges[@(type)] = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:sectionIndex];
        }
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *changeSet = _objectChanges[@(type)];
    if (changeSet == nil) {
        changeSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _objectChanges[@(type)] = changeSet;
    }

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [changeSet addObject:newIndexPath];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [changeSet addObject:indexPath];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [changeSet addObject:indexPath];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [changeSet addObject:@[indexPath, newIndexPath]];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
// End updates
    NSMutableArray *moves = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)];
    if (moves.count > 0) {
        NSMutableArray *updatedMoves = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:moves.count];

        NSMutableIndexSet *insertSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
        NSMutableIndexSet *deleteSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
        for (NSArray *move in moves) {
            NSIndexPath *fromIP = move[0];
            NSIndexPath *toIP = move[1];

            if ([deleteSections containsIndex:fromIP.section]) {
                if (![insertSections containsIndex:toIP.section]) {
                    NSMutableArray *changeSet = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
                    if (changeSet == nil) {
                        changeSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:toIP, nil];
                        _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)] = changeSet;
                    } else {
                        [changeSet addObject:toIP];
                    }
                }
            } else if ([insertSections containsIndex:toIP.section]) {
                NSMutableArray *changeSet = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
                if (changeSet == nil) {
                    changeSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:fromIP, nil];
                    _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)] = changeSet;
                } else {
                    [changeSet addObject:fromIP];
                }
            } else {
                [updatedMoves addObject:move];
            }
        }

        if (updatedMoves.count > 0) {
            _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)] = updatedMoves;
        } else {
            [_objectChanges removeObjectForKey:@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)];
        }
    }

    NSMutableArray *deletes = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
    if (deletes.count > 0) {
        NSMutableIndexSet *deletedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
        [deletes filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSIndexPath *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            return ![deletedSections containsIndex:evaluatedObject.section];
        }]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *inserts = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
    if (inserts.count > 0) {
        NSMutableIndexSet *insertedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
        [inserts filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSIndexPath *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            return ![insertedSections containsIndex:evaluatedObject.section];
        }]];
    }

    UICollectionView *collectionView = self.collectionView;

    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        NSIndexSet *deletedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
        if (deletedSections.count > 0) {
            [collectionView deleteSections:deletedSections];
        }

        NSIndexSet *insertedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
        if (insertedSections.count > 0) {
            [collectionView insertSections:insertedSections];
        }

        NSArray *deletedItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
        if (deletedItems.count > 0) {
            [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:deletedItems];
        }

        NSArray *insertedItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
        if (insertedItems.count > 0) {
            [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:insertedItems];
        }

        NSArray *reloadItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate)];
        if (reloadItems.count > 0) {
            [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:reloadItems];
        }

        NSArray *moveItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)];
        for (NSArray *paths in moveItems) {
            [collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:paths[0] toIndexPath:paths[1]];
        }
    } completion:nil];

    _objectChanges = nil;
    _sectionChanges = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the records will be changing while you are in the collection view and you want to track that, use a fetched results controller. They're designed for table views but are simple enough to adapt for a collection view.

Otherwise, set a batch size on your fetch request. This will ensure that only a certain number of records are fetched from the store at once, and will be turned back into faults if they are not accessed. From the documentation:

> If you set a non-zero batch size, the collection of objects returned when the fetch is executed is broken into batches. When the fetch is executed, the entire request is evaluated and the identities of all matching objects recorded, but no more than batchSize objects’ data will be fetched from the persistent store at a time. The array returned from executing the request will be a proxy object that transparently faults batches on demand. (In database terms, this is an in-memory cursor.)